# Html5 Breeze offline solution

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application

I watched John Papa's (http://www.johnpapa.net/spa/) spa example. He is using Knockout, Breeze to build single page application. I wanted to build spa but I want my data to be in local storage not on server (so that user can have their data locally). I successfully added metadata (in javascript with metadataStore.addEntityType, not from server) and create entity manager.createEntity(entityNames.teacher, { id: breeze.core.getUuid() })

I also use exportEntities to get whole database and save that json into localstorage. I use importEntities to import that json into breeze manager. But every time I wanted to do query with executeQueryLocally I get an error (I can see one entity that I just added inside json):
There is no metadata available for this query

John Papa's example first do query on server, and later do query from cache (locally). Is it possible to query locally without first fetch from server? Do I need breeze? Breeze looks fine for me because I can do queries (getting error) and also because of that import/export capabilities.

**EDIT**

First I created entity

```
var et = new breeze.EntityType({ shortName: "Teacher", namespace: "AIKON.Timetable", autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity, }); 

et.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({ name: "id", dataType: breeze.DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true })); 

et.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({ name: "firstName", dataType: breeze.DataType.String, isNullable: false, maxLength: 50, validators: [Validator.required(), Validator.maxLength({ maxLength: 50 })] })); 

et.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({ name: "lastName", dataType: breeze.DataType.String, isNullable: false, maxLength: 50, validators: [Validator.required(), Validator.maxLength({ maxLength: 50 })] })); 

store.addEntityType(et); 
store.registerEntityTypeCtor("Teacher", null, teacherInitializer);
```

Then I can get all teachers with (but I do not have query, order etc)

```
var list = manager.getEntities('Teacher').sort(compareTeachers);
```

but

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('AIKON.Timetable.Teacher') 

return manager.executeQueryLocally(query);
```

throw error throw new

```
Error("There is no metadata available for this query"); breeze.debug.js (line 7224)
```

same with

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('Teacher')
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when calling executeQueryLocally?

Comment: I will bet that the problem is that Breeze cannot associate the resource name (the 'Foos' in `EntityQuery.from('Foos')`) with an entity type. I'll collect my bet when you show us the entity type name (Foo) and the query that your are executing.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to your problem? I would be interested to know.

Comment: i used
var list = manager.getEntities('Teacher').sort(compareTeachers);

Comment: Then you can user filter
list = list.filter(function (element, index, array) {
return !element.isDeleted();
});